# Using Select Same function on similar paths

Tags: inkscape

So, I imported a pdf chart for a knitting pattern into Inkscape. See image attached. Everything imported as paths.

Is there a way to select a group of paths (in this case, see the circle with a line, at the edges), and do a Select Same so I can select all "circles with a line through it" for the whole document?

Is there a way or technique to select all "circle with a line through it" since they are all paths? I hope this makes sense.[image: Example import]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'Edit → Find/Replace...' dialog (<kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd>) to select objects with similar attributes and styles. It requires a bit of knowledge about the underlying SVG and XML code, but is very powerful.

Just switch the 'Search in' setting from 'Text' to 'Properties' and enter some value they all have in common. It might be helpful to use the 'Edit → XML-Editor...' to inspect the attributes of one of them and find something you can search for. If they all have the same path-data, for example, then you can copy-and-paste a short snippet from the `d` attribute into the search-box and click the 'Find' button.

There are also more search settings in the expandable 'Options' section to narrow down the results.

Comment: Oh wow!!! Sorry I am responding so late. I didn't get a notification that the answer has been updated. But that solved everything!!! I find all by the style: <br/> -"display:inline;fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.50503;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"<br/> which seemed unique to the "circle with the line through it" and it worked!!! Thanks so much!! <br/>BTW, what does the "d" attribute mean? is it the coordinates of the path on the page?

Comment: The ```d``` attribute is the path-*data*. It describes how the renderer should draw the shape. Basically a list of commands and coordinates as parameters – e.g. ```L 10,20``` to draw a line to x 10 and y 20, or ```C 10,20 30,40, 50,60``` for a Bezier-curve to x 50 y 60 with the control-points at the other coordinates.

Comment: Thanks again!! This works!!